# How to load environment variables in the Rails console?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, environment-variables, irb, foreman

I think this is a little, easy question!

I'm using `.env` file to keep all my environment variables, and i'm using `foreman`.

Unfortunately, these environment variables are not being loaded when running rails console `rails c` so, i'm now loading them manually after running the console, which is not the best way.

I'd like to know if there any better way for that.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

About a year ago, the "run" command was added to `foreman`

ref: https://github.com/ddollar/foreman/pull/121

You can use it as follow:

`foreman run rails console`

or

`foreman run rake db:migrate`

Answer (score 2):

rails does not know about the environmental variables specified in .env file as it is specific to foreman. You need to set the environment explicitly before invoking rails console. Have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5715157/read-run-environment-variables-in-a-text-file).

Answer (score 1):

I personnaly use [dotenv](https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv) in development and testing environements. With this approach, you don't have to prefix your commands, just call the initializer in your `config/application.rb` :

```
Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)

Dotenv::Railtie.load

HOSTNAME = ENV['HOSTNAME']
```